# My max and min program is working for some values but also not working for some values

Tags: python, list

Rewrite the program that prompts the user for a list of
numbers and prints out the maximum and minimum of the numbers at
the end when the user enters “done”. Write the program to store the
numbers the user enters in a list and use the max() and min() functions to
compute the maximum and minimum numbers after the loop completes.

```
lst=[]
while True:
    
    data=input('Enter the Input : ')
    if data == 'done':
        break
    else:
        lst.append(data)
        

print(lst)
print('The maximum number of list is ',max(lst))
print('The minimum number of list is ',min(lst))
```

```
Enter the Input : done
['1234', '1256', '1897', '1368']
The maximum number of list is  1897
The minimum number of list is  1234 ///// giving correct answer
```

Giving me wrong answer with the same code:

```
Enter the Input : done
['12', '212', '32']
The maximum number of list is  32
The minimum number of list is  12
```

Comment: `max(lst, key=int)`

Comment: Can u please explain why

Comment: because you are storing number as string. you don't need list just use two variables `min_number` and `max_number` update them after each input

Comment: The `key` is a callable which will take the elements of the list and return an object used as a sort key. In this case, e.g. `int('212')` will return `212`. You need to compare integer values because lexically sorting the strings will give the wrong ordering. [EDIT: correction, we are not sorting here - we are obtaining the maximum. But it is the same issue, because in both situations it depends on comparisons between values, and which value should be considered to be the higher.]

Comment: Alternatively, put integers on the list in the first place:  `lst.append(int(data))`

Comment: because `'11' > '100'` but `11 < 100`

Comment: got it thanks deadshot ,alani

Answer (score 0):

Your `lst` is an array of strings. Therefore `min` and `max` use lexicographic ordering, where of course, for instance, `"10"` is less than `"3"`. Convert your input to numeric values before adding them to your list.

```
lst.append(int(data))
```

So you will get a list of numbers, then `min`and `max` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using max()/min() on a list of strings, you want to to be a list of integers (or float)

You just need to convert each bit of data added by the user, and can write a check to make sure this is a number if desired,

```
lst=[]
while True:
    
    data=input('Enter the Input : ')
    if data == 'done':
        break
    try: 
        lst.append(int(data))
    except ValueError:
        print('Input must be a number! Please try again.')
        

print(lst)
print('The maximum number of list is ',max(lst))
print('The minimum number of list is ',min(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        numList = list()
        while True:
            num = input('Enter a number: ')
            if num == 'done':
                break
            else:
                try:
                    num = float(num)
                    numList.append(num)
                except:
                    print('Invalid number')
        if len(numList) != 0:
            print('Maximum:', max(numList))
            print('Minimum:', min(numList))
        else:
            print('List is empty!')
```

Comment: I would like to correct you: It's possible to write a more complete answer. e.g. one where the code has no syntax errors, or one which contains an explanation of the code and how it addresses the problem stated in the question.